# Inspect TSA timestamp

Tags: trusted-timestamp, xades4j, timestamping

I'm trying to validate a XAdES signature with a *SignatureTimeStamp*-element (which is a base64-encoded block). The Java-Lib xades4j basically does the validation for me. However, I'd like to manually inspect the timestamp (especially when validation fails). With *inspect* I mean to show the contents like the used certificates, their validity, the timestamp, etc.

What tool can I use? Does openssl do the trick? Can you give me an example of how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Xades4j uses Bouncy Castle to generate and validate timestamps. BC probably allows you to get that info from the timestamp token in the signature.